# Django and Tastypie: How to POST a new resource and created related resources in one go?

Tags: django, tastypie

I am trying to create a resource and related resources in one go, but I get an error. What am I doing wrong?

This is my code and what I am trying to POST:

**Models**

```python
class Asset(models.Model):
    basename = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.basename

class CommonAssetLocation(models.Model):
    asset = models.ForeignKey(Asset, related_name='%(class)s_locations')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class LocalDirectory(CommonAssetLocation):
    directory = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.directory
```

**The API resources**

```python
class AssetResource(ModelResource):
    localdirectory_locations = fields.ToManyField(to='ondemandbackend.api.LocalDirectoryResource', attribute='localdirectory_locations', related_name='localdirectory_location', full=True)

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'asset'
        queryset = Asset.objects.all()
        authorization = Authorization()

class LocalDirectoryResource(ModelResource):
    asset = fields.ToOneField(to='ondemandbackend.api.AssetResource', attribute='asset', related_name='asset')

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'localdirectory_location'
        queryset = LocalDirectory.objects.all()
        authorization = Authorization()
```

**How to provoke the error**

```
curl --dump-header - --header 'Content-Type: application/xml' -X POST -d @post_asset.xml 'http://localhost:8000/ondemandbackend/api/v1/asset/'
```

**Contents of post_asset.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object>
  <basename>post_test</basename>
  <localdirectory_locations type="list">
    <object>
      <directory>/tmp/hello/sup_again3</directory>
    </object>
    <object>
      <directory>/tmp/hello/sup_again2</directory>
    </object>
  </localdirectory_locations>
</object>
```

**Output from Curl**

```
HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND Date: Mon, 11 Feb 2013 13:09:28 GMT Server:
WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.3 Content-Type: application/json;
charset=utf-8

{
"error_message": "", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tastypie/resources.py", line 192, in wrapper  response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "tastypie/resources.py", line 397, in dispatch_list  return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)
File "tastypie/resources.py", line 427, in dispatch  response = method(request, **kwargs)
File "tastypie/resources.py", line 1165, in post_list  updated_bundle = self.obj_create(bundle, request=request, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))
File "tastypie/resources.py", line 1783, in obj_create  m2m_bundle = self.hydrate_m2m(bundle)
File "tastypie/resources.py", line 743, in hydrate_m2m  bundle.data[field_name] = field_object.hydrate_m2m(bundle) 
File "tastypie/fields.py", line 742, in hydrate_m2m  m2m_hydrated.append(self.build_related_resource(value, **kwargs))
File "tastypie/fields.py", line 593, in build_related_resource  return self.resource_from_data(self.fk_resource, value, **kwargs)
File "tastypie/fields.py", line 559, in resource_from_data  return fk_resource.full_hydrate(fk_bundle)
File "tastypie/resources.py", line 698, in full_hydrate  value = field_object.hydrate(bundle)
File "tastypie/fields.py", line 636, in hydrate  value = super(ToOneField, self).hydrate(bundle)
File "tastypie/fields.py", line 154, in hydrate  elif self.attribute and getattr(bundle.obj, self.attribute, None):
File "django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 343, in __get__  raise self.field.rel.to.DoesNotExist
}
```

Comment: You got 404 server error, that means you have problem with the post url or your resources are not registered to the api.

Comment: You have a `ToOneField` to your AssetResource which you aren't populating in your POST request, in TastyPie it always seems to look up related fields regardless of whether it gets the attribute in the POST, hence it fails when trying to find the non-populated field. I am unsure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass in the `resource_uri` like described in the doc:

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"body": "This will prbbly be my lst post.", "pub_date": "2011-05-22T00:46:38", "slug": "another-post", "title": "Another Post", "user": "/api/v1/user/1/"}' http://localhost:8000/api/v1/entry/
```

That's the `"user": "/api/v1/user/1/"` part. I haven't worked with XML or m2m fields before but to me it doesn't seem like you are doing that.

I got the same error as you when omitted that part.